# Solidworks macro problem with selection and creation of fillet

Tags: vba, selection, solidworks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8eXZ.png)Solidworks macro problem with selection and creation of fillet.

Hi.
I have a problem with a macro.
I created 32 elements by extrusion from one plane to
another element, merged results, and now need to add fillets
on each edge.
To do this, I used a for cycle but there are many problems
because the program doesn’t create all the fillets needed,
but only a few (6) or it connects the elements.
In my macro I used SelectById2 command for selection
because I know the coordinates of the edges and while
running the program the window and zoom are optimized,
so you can see the blue lines of selection.
I tried to use SelectByRay but it doesn’t work correctly as it
selects the external side of another element.
FeatureFillet3 is the command to make fillets, that are
symmetric.
I tried to use FeatureFillet3 inside and outside the for cycle,
but in the first case the macro created only the first six and
in the second it merged some elements.
I used a for cycle because the number of the elements can
change, and I need a selection via coordinates of their
edges.
Thanks

This my code in vba.

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
Dim Part As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
Dim boolstatus As Boolean
Dim longstatus As Long, longwarnings As Long
Dim swModView As SldWorks.ModelView

Sub main()

Set swApp = Application.SldWorks

Set Part = swApp.ActiveDoc
Set swModView = Part.ActiveView
Dim passo, i As Double
Dim delta_y, x_0, z As Double
x_0 = 159.26 / 1000
z = -1 / 1000
Dim x_angle, y_angle As Double
x_angle = -45
y_angle = 0

For i = 0 To 7
passo = (3.16 / 1000)
delta_y = (-5.5 / 1000) + (i * passo)
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2("", "EDGE", x_0, delta_y, z, True, 1, Nothing, 0)
Next

Dim radiiArray0 As Variant
Dim radiis0 As Double
Dim dist2Array0 As Variant
Dim dists20 As Double
Dim conicRhosArray0 As Variant
Dim coniRhos0 As Double
Dim setBackArray0 As Variant
Dim setBacks0 As Double
Dim pointArray0 As Variant
Dim points0 As Double
Dim pointDist2Array0 As Variant
Dim pointsDist20 As Double
Dim pointRhoArray0 As Variant
Dim pointsRhos0 As Double
radiiArray0 = radiis0
dist2Array0 = dists20
conicRhosArray0 = coniRhos0
setBackArray0 = setBacks0
pointArray0 = points0
pointDist2Array0 = pointsDist20
pointRhoArray0 = pointsRhos0
Dim myFeature As SldWorks.Feature
Set myFeature = Part.FeatureManager.FeatureFillet3(195, 0.001, 0#, 0, 0, 0, 0, (radiiArray0), (dist2Array0), (conicRhosArray0), (setBackArray0), (pointArray0), (pointDist2Array0), (pointRhoArray0))

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you edit your question to provide your macro code and perhaps an example part file to perform testing? If you can't supply a part file, at least show how it's constructed in the feature tree so a similar part can be replicated.

Comment: Thanks for your advise.Iput my macro code and an image of my model.Whats your opinion about my question?

Answer (score 0):

you can create 1 filet feature per body, If you created 32 separate elements, or 32 separate bodies, fileting them all at once won't work. I suggest you create an element, then add fillets, then create another one, and so forth.